# How to convert character from an array into a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm having difficulty appending a character value of an array onto a string `(handSorted)`. The `hand[]` is a predefined array of text.

```
char *handSorted = malloc(strlen(hand)+1);
strcat(handSorted, hand[2]);
```

For example I would like `handSorted` to be a string of the value of `hand[2]`, the letter 'A'.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: In C, sorry added that to the tag now.

Comment: You can use a for loop, you can use memset, you can use strdup and many other/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with C, it is good to learn how to use the manual pages in the terminal. Here is the entry for strcat.

```
DESCRIPTION
 The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the 
 null-terminated string s2 to the end of the null-terminated
 string s1, then add a terminating `\0'.
```

That's one problem. You need handSorted to be null terminated.

```
char *handSorted = malloc(strlen(hand)+1);
handSorted[0] = '\0';
strcat(handSorted, hand[2]);
```

But there is still a problem. `hand[2]` is a single character, and strcat() expects a character pointer, AKA a string. So you need to pass it the address of a character using the 'address-of' operator - the &. Like this.

```
char *handSorted = malloc(strlen(hand)+1);
handSorted[0] = '\0';
strcat(handSorted, &hand[2]);
```

I think that is what you we're after.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I had the null termination already, forgot to add stupidly, but the character pointer helped me so much! Thank you!

Comment: Dai, can you explain a bit more? This code snippet I have provided is very short and without more information it is hard to know if my snippet will work in all cases. But I don't see why hand[3] != '\0' would cause it to fail.

Comment: As I understand the given variables, `handSorted` and `hand` are both type of `char*`, now with this at mind, assuming `handSorted[0] == '\0'`, `strcat` would perform the same as `hand.substr(2, hand.length - 1)`. [See for yourself](http://ideone.com/iohb7u)

Comment: Not quite. Your example is exactly what I expected, and what should occur given my solution. Rereading the original question now I see what Dai meant with his comment. The original question just wanted to store a single character into `handSorted`. But since he was using `char*` and `strcat` I made the (incorrect) assumption that he wanted to be working with strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcat` function expects both arguments to be null-terminated strings (pointers, too), as you're passing into a character by value this is going to lead to undefined behavior (probably a segfault crash as it would try to read a low memory address likely outside an allocated area).

If you're adding a single character, you might as well just set the character value directly:

```
size_t charLength = strlen( handSorted );
assert( charLength < sizeof( handSorted ) + 1 ); // assuming handSorted hasn't decomposed from char[N] to char*.
handSorted[ charLength     ] = hand[2]; // overwrite existing null-terminator with desired char
handSorted[ charLength + 1 ] = '\0'; // set new null-terminator
```